# Can you get information for a data view web part to show presence bubble using SOAP connection?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, web-services, data-view-web-part, people-picker

I am trying to set up a data view web part to show information from a list on a different site collection in the same web application. The information I need to get includes people with their presence bubble and a choice value. I have been struggling with this for a while now, so to try and sort it out I've gone down a few paths in SPDesigner.

1. The SOAP connection 
   Connection string: `http://<url of site collection>/_vti_bin/list.asmx?WSDL`
   I selected the `GetListItems` drop down and added the name of the list name as the filter.
   The people come back in the XML `<92;#Peter Griffin>`.
   I was told that this was not in fact the users id, but the id that is assigned to that user when they first visit that particular iste collection. So not enough information there to get the presence.
2. REST connection
   Connection string: `http://{url}/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={list GUID}&XMLDATA=TRUE`.
   I've tried this with/without the View GUID too
3. XML Data
   I can't actually get this one working
4. Creating a list within the site to see what the XML sould be displayed like to get the bubble. Each person field is made up of 4 XML elements that show 1, the whole string to be output {user}, 2 the id, 3 title, 4 span to be inserted with JavaScript (I think) 
   [image: owner field xml]

I'm not too sure whether I should start tackling external lists/content types yet. The list is already set up and someone has made custom web parts that point to it (C#). They said that they couldn't get the presence bubble out in the project and I don't know C#, so I was hoping there was a way I could do it in SPDesigner with some XSL possibly?

If anyone has any suggestions I would love love love to hear from you! I'm going insane! Each step has taken a while to get working and still no closer.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You needn't "in fact the users id", you can show presence bubble with HTML like this:

```
<img width="12" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" onload="IMNRC('[USERMAIL]')" id="uniqueId" ShowOfflinePawn=1 alt="Presence bubble">[USERNAME]</span>
```

view [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637915/adding-presence-indicator-to-a-custom-web-part) for detail.

add the following to the call to [retrieve user email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379403/get-email-id-of-user-in-spservices)

```
<ExpandUserField>TRUE</ExpandUserField>
```

Comment: The only thing is I can't get the XML data from another site collection to show the email for the presence bubble. The first 3 options above were the ways I tried to get XML out of the list to see if one method gave me that data. But I got the XML link working for a different list using people fields and it still doesn't show the email.
Is there any way of connecting to the list where I could get that information out?

Comment: It says [USERMAIL] in the code, but I don't have the usermail info coming out in the XML

Comment: set "ExpandUserField" to true. when you query a User field, you only see the login name of the user. When you indicate that you want to expand a user field, SharePoint will also return information like the user name and the email address.